# JavaScript - Why when I add new columns to my table it says "undefined" in the extra cells

Tags: javascript

When I add an extra 3 columns to the table my list items do not fill them. Instead it says undefined in the cells. If anyone can I ideally need a 6x6 table for my list items. Cheers.

```
var listOfWords = ["mat", "cat", "dog", "pit", "pot", "fog", "log", "pan", "can", "man", "pin", "gag", "sat", "pat", "tap", "sap", "tag", "gig", "gap", "nag", "sag", "gas", "pig", "dig", "got", "not", "top", "pop", "god", "mog", "cot", "cop", "cap", "cod", "kid", "kit", "get", "pet", "ten", "net", "pen", "peg", "met", "men", "mum", "run", "mug", "cup", "sun", "mud", "rim", "ram", "rat", "rip", "rag", "rug", "rot", "dad", "sad", "dim", "dip", "did", "mam", "map", "nip", "tin", "tan", "nap", "sit", "tip", "pip", "sip", "had", "him", "his", "hot", "hut", "hop", "hum", "hit", "hat", "has", "hug", "but", "big", "bet", "bad", "bad", "bed", "bud", "beg", "bug", "bun", "bus", "bat", "bit", "fit", "fin", "fun", "fig", "fan", "fat", "lap", "lot", "let", "leg", "lit" ];

var shuffledWords = listOfWords.slice(0, 6);
 shuffledWords.sort(function () {
   return 0.5 - Math.random();
});

var tbl = document.createElement('table');
tbl.className='tablestyle';

 for (var i = 0; i < shuffledWords.length; i++) {
   var word = shuffledWords[i];
   var row = document.createElement('tr');
 //Here is where I add the extra 3 columns
 for (var j = 0; j < word.length + 3; j++){
   var cell = document.createElement('td');


    cell.textContent = word[j];
    // IF FIREFOX USE cell.textContent = word[j]; INSTEAD
    row.appendChild(cell);
  }

  tbl.appendChild(row);    
}

document.body.appendChild(tbl);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to display two words per line, you can do this:

```
var listOfWords = ["mat", "cat", "dog", "pit", "pot", "fog", "log", "pan", "can", "man", "pin", "gag", "sat", "pat", "tap", "sap", "tag", "gig", "gap", "nag", "sag", "gas", "pig", "dig", "got", "not", "top", "pop", "god", "mog", "cot", "cop", "cap", "cod", "kid", "kit", "get", "pet", "ten", "net", "pen", "peg", "met", "men", "mum", "run", "mug", "cup", "sun", "mud", "rim", "ram", "rat", "rip", "rag", "rug", "rot", "dad", "sad", "dim", "dip", "did", "mam", "map", "nip", "tin", "tan", "nap", "sit", "tip", "pip", "sip", "had", "him", "his", "hot", "hut", "hop", "hum", "hit", "hat", "has", "hug", "but", "big", "bet", "bad", "bad", "bed", "bud", "beg", "bug", "bun", "bus", "bat", "bit", "fit", "fin", "fun", "fig", "fan", "fat", "lap", "lot", "let", "leg", "lit" ];

var shuffledWords = listOfWords.slice(0).sort(function () {
    return 0.5 - Math.random();
}).slice(0, 12);

var tbl = document.createElement('table');
tbl.className='tablestyle';
var wordsPerRow = 2;

for (var i = 0; i < shuffledWords.length; i += wordsPerRow) {
    var row = document.createElement('tr');

    for (var j=i; j < i + wordsPerRow; ++ j) {
        var word = shuffledWords[j];

        for (var k = 0; k < word.length; k++){
            var cell = document.createElement('td');


            cell.textContent = word[k];
            // IF FIREFOX USE cell.textContent = word[j]; INSTEAD
            row.appendChild(cell);
        }
    }
    tbl.appendChild(row);    
}

document.body.appendChild(tbl);
```

Added a demonstration of this: http://jsfiddle.net/Ks2Nk/

Comment: my list items still don't populate the 3 extra columns though

Comment: They are added in the DOM, but are empty. What values do you want them to have?

Comment: But he want them to be filled. not empty, read the question once again @Razvi

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to add on the extra columns ... Do you want to display 2 items on one row, each having 3 columns? Thus trying to display 12 items?

Comment: The +3 adds the extra column to my table but the words are not filling the cells when they are made @Razvi

Comment: I updated the code to display 2 words on each row ... is this the behavior you want?

Comment: created a fiddle, with the javascript version, at http://jsfiddle.net/flaviocysne/PqMWa/7/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you trying to randomise the letters in the 6x6 row

If not try

```
cell.textContent = word[j%3];
```

But this will simply repeat the word

So for example for mat

you'll have

m   a   t   m   a   t

Comment: Thanks but doesn't work. Is there a way I can say every 6 rows make new column? @Kamal

Comment: How many rows do you want from this, can you show a sample output expected